# Is there a kanji tattoo meaning e.g. "live your life" or "love your life" or "be yourself"?

Tags: characters

I'm thinking of getting a tattoo on my wrist, one saying: "Live your life" or  "love your life" or "be yourself" in kanji.  (Not more then 2 characters if possible.)

I asked on the Japanese Stack Exchange and I got sent here.

Comment: LINE dict. live your life 过好你的生活, just live your life  好好过你的生活,(fervently) love your life 热爱自己的生命 be yourself 做自己,

Comment: First, are you looking for a Chinese rather than a Japanese translation? Second, would it not be better to pick an authentic proverb or literary quote directly from Chinese?

Comment: Since it's permanent, whatever you decide on, be sure to firrst show it to several native speakers, ask them "*What does this mean?*", and see if you like the answers.  Do not ask a leading question like "*Does this mean …?*" (like asking "Does '[obscene expression]' mean 'don't bother me'?", and being told "yes it does").

Comment: Not sure why they'd send you here? The meaning of any suggestions you get here won't necessarily be the same in Japanese

Comment: You need to add more info about yourself, e.g. I really like 猛志(from 刑天舞干戚，猛志固常在), but it is not fit an elegant female, so it is hard to give any suggestions.

Comment: Given that you don't seem to have much preference between Japanese or Chinese, why don't you just get it in English? That way you'll know for sure what it means.

Answer (score 1):

自爱 (love; respect oneself)

爱生命 (love life)

我是我 (I am myself)

Comment: Ｈｏｗ would you feel about "随缘" for this tattoo context? I feel like the three OP suggestions are variations on a kind of 顺其自然 philosophy, 随缘 might be a 2-character way of expressing that? Interested to see your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

live your life: 好好生活
love your life: 热爱生活
be yourself: 做自己

Comment: I think the reason this post is down voted is because 'life'  in 'live your life' is '人生' not '生活' ; 'live your life' should be '活你的人生'